# How to dowload files with original timestamp?

Tags: wget, browser-addons, curl, cookies, browser-plugin

Many web sites ask us to login before downloading real contents files, and restrict us to download files from it with a cli program such as **wget** or **curl**.

So we must download files with a browser, instead of wget/curl.
But this way, the **modified time** of files are the time of the downloading action, not the real modified time.

I want to get the **real modified time**. Is there a easy way to do it? or a add-on/extension of browsers( **Chromium / FireFox** )?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe check out the "cliget" Firefox extension. It doesn't do what you ask but could be interesting nonetheless.

Comment: If the file is zipped, although the zip file itself is not the correct date, the content inside is.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks a lot!!! I tried this extension, it works, at least let me downloaded successfully a file from Nvidia develop site with wget!

Answer (score 2):

See
[Time-Stamping Usage](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping-Usage.html#Time_002dStamping-Usage).

Basically, if the web-server returns a `Last-Modified` header for
`wget`, then to set the local last-modified time to the origin's
date-time, use:

```
wget -S URL
```

This will work for both HTTP(S) and FTP.

---

As far as Firefox is concerned, this was discussed since
20 years ago and during many years in the post
[save original last-modified date on file downloads](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=178506).

Finally, this was rejected and the following workaround was
proposed:

- Install an older version of Firefox (specifically, Firefox 52.9.0 ESR, not a version higher!)
- Install an older version of DownThemAll (specifically,
  https://code.downthemall.net/releases/downthemall-3.0.7.xpi)

This combination is the last one that will preserve the
last-modified time.

---

As regarding Chrome, this was also discussed in the
long-running post
[Issue 4574: Feature request: preserve timestamps on downloaded files](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4574),
but nothing ever came out of it.

**Conclusion** : Seems like wget is the only one, the browsers
won't do it, by design.

Comment: OP wants a browser-based solution.

Comment: But many web sites doesn't allow us to use wget, they enforce us to login before we can download anything.

Comment: I extended my answer. Wget is finally the only option.